# Why is WordPress wrapping search for users that looks like integers with asterisks and how do I fix it?

Tags: plugin-development, search

I've got a custom meta field for users called "user_ein". It looks like an integer but is a string of number and it can start with the number "0". I have the following code in a custom plugin so users can be searched on this number:

```php
function search_by_user_ein( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() || ! $query->query_vars['search'] ) {
        return $query;
    }
    global $wpdb;
    $search = trim( $query->query_vars['search'] );
    // Uncomment next line to get search working on user_ein field
    // $search = trim( $search, '*' );
    $search = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search ) . '%';

    $query->query_from .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} ON {$wpdb->users}.ID = {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id";

    $query->query_where .= $wpdb->prepare( " OR ({$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'user_ein' AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value LIKE %s)", $search );
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'search_by_user_ein' );
```

This didn't work. If I put in "552398" into the search field, nothing was returned even though there is a user with the user_ein. After some head scraching, I dumped out the query and noticed that it was searching on `*552398*`. The search term was getting surrounded by asterisks.

To fix the problem, I added this code in after getting the search term from the `$query` object:

```php
$search = trim( $search, '*' );
```

Things seem to work perfectly now but I'm worried there might be some unintended consequences. Is there a better fix than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The search term was getting surrounded by asterisks.

Yes, and they are [wildcard characters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/#search-parameters), and in the case of the Users list table at `wp-admin/users.php`, those asterisks are being added by `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-users-list-table.php` ([see source on GitHub for WordPress v6.1](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6c5d5b5dcb9712bfc400b09cb6627e42898527af/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-users-list-table.php#L113-L115)), so that a `LIKE '%<keyword>%'` query is performed by default.

So to fix the issue, yes, I'd also use `trim( $search, '*' )`. But you can also use the *raw* search keyword, e.g. using `$_REQUEST['s']`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware they are wild card characters but it doesn't make sense to me that no matches are returned with the asterisks in there. I'm using LIKE already. So maybe the asterisks and LIKE don't play well together?

Comment: Part of what confused is I mistakenly thought strings were not wrapped with `*`. But I was looking at the wrong part of the dump. Strings are also wrapped with them.

Comment: Odd, even this simple query returns nothing: `select user_id from wp_usermeta where meta_value = '*aldez';` but it should find the user.

Comment: "So maybe the asterisks and LIKE don't play well together?" - I was saying that `*` is used by WordPress, regardless with strings or numbers. But when sent to MySQL, WordPress will use `%`. So, `*foo*` would actually be `%foo%`. See the [`WP_User_Query::get_search_sql()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/get_search_sql/), specifically [these lines](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/28f10e4af559c9b4dbbd1768feff0bae575d5e78/src/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php#L917-L919).

Comment: So that means, you need to remove that `*`, or simply convert it to `%`, because you're constructing your own SQL command. Make sense?

Comment: OK, gotcha. I leapt to an assumption that asterisks were a glob in mysql I had not encountered before.